# What's the best way to fix this radio button HTML?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, radio-button

I'm working with a shopping cart product that puts out some rather old fashioned HTML. Since it's dynamically generated by the cart, PDG Commerce, I don't have control of the HTML tag structure.

Here's a sample:

```
<p class='ups_address_suggest'>
    <input type="radio" name="addrvalselect" value="3" onclick="setaddr2();">DULUTH, MN &nbsp;&nbsp;55810 
    <input type="radio" name="addrvalselect" value="4" onclick="setaddr3();">DULUTH, MN &nbsp;&nbsp;55811 
    <input type="radio" name="addrvalselect" value="5" onclick="setaddr4();">DULUTH, MN &nbsp;&nbsp;55812 
    <input type="radio" name="addrvalselect" value="6" onclick="setaddr5();">HERMANTOWN, MN &nbsp;&nbsp;55810 
    <input type="radio" name="addrvalselect" value="7" onclick="setaddr6();">HERMANTOWN, MN &nbsp;&nbsp;55811 
    <input type="radio" name="addrvalselect" value="8" onclick="setaddr7();">BOWDON JUNCTION, GA &nbsp;&nbsp;30109 
</p>
```

As shown above it outputs the radio buttons with text next to them, which is not in a label element.

I'm trying to style this so it looks decent. So far I've tried applying CSS to the input elements (display:block, float:left, etc) but that leaves the text in odd places like the next line or all bunched together while the buttons float left.

Using jQuery, I've been unable so far to get the text and input as a unit to wrap them in a label or `<p>` or whatever.

Here's how the current output looks in a browser:
[image: unstyled buttons]

Any suggestions for a javascript and/or jQuery way to fix this? Or a way to have the buttons formatted neatly next to the text labels using just CSS.

Comment: What do you want the output to look like?

Comment: Define "decent" please.  How would you ultimately like it to display?

Comment: Sorry I wasn't more clear. I reckon, just wrap the text or each pair in tags so I can further style them. Each input/label on it's own line would be good.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This works for me in the console (Chrome):

jQuery:

```
$('p.ups_address_suggest input').each(function (i, elem) {
    var self = $(elem),                             // cache DOM lookup
        text = $(elem.nextSibling).detach(),        // remove text and jQuerify
        label = $('<label />').text(text.text());   // add to a new label
    label.insertAfter(self);                        // insert label into DOM
});
```

CSS:

```
p.ups_address_suggest input, p.ups_address_suggest label {float: left;}
p.ups_address_suggest input {clear: left;}
```

Here's a fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/xb42s/

Comment: groovy, that's what I was looking for I reckon - the nextSibling. I wasn't sure how to select the text node. Thanks for the complete answer.

Comment: Fiddle updated with `ids` on the inputs and `for` attributes on the labels: http://jsfiddle.net/xb42s/1/

Answer (score 1):

Here is a solution i came up with. It's not perfect, but it works for that case:

```
$('p.ups_address_suggest').html(
    $('p.ups_address_suggest').html().replace(/(\<input.*?\d{5})/g,'<label>$1</label>')
);
```

The regex searches from `<input..` until 5 digits and wraps that in a label. That should give you more styling options.

http://jsfiddle.net/nxFbN/

Comment: Cool, that works! Thanks for the alternate method. I'd probably like to do it with DOM methods rather than regex so I think I'll implement the code pete suggested.

Answer (score 0):

If you want them to be inline, put each pair of input/text in a span, else in a p (or use br after each input) and that should look more neat.

Comment: I would love to, but those input tags are output by a single opaque PDG template tag, <!---UPS_ADDR_SUGGEST--->. I have no control of the HTML within the <p>.